# Reference ID using a Class suffix integer

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Situation:

There are many checkboxes, this is only a small part of a tree:

```
<li class="main">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat_6" class="parent_cat_0" name="local[]">
    <label class="strong" for="cat_6">Stellenbeschreibungen</label>
    <ul>
        <li class="main">
            <input type="checkbox" id="doc_31" class="parent_cat_6" name="local[]">
            <label for="doc_31">Stellenbeschreibung Marketing/Vertrieb</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I want to make a selector for parent of this checkbox that has class "parent_cat_6"

So the final selector should be:

```
let parent = $('#cat_6');
```

But I don't know how to cut off the 'parent_' out of checked checkbox class.

```
child has class="parent_cat_6"
parent has id="cat_6"
```

Do I need to use regex to make selector for the parent or there is another way?

UPDATE:
This works:

```
selected.attr('class').split(' ').slice(-1)[0].substr(7);
```

But it's ugly, any improvements are welcome!

Comment: `'parent_cat_6'.replace(/^parent_/, '')`, that said, you could make this many times more efficient and robust if you used common classes on all the elements in the tree and DOM traversal to relate them to each other instead.

Comment: actually there are 2 more classes in the tree I didn't want to write them in question

Comment: The approach is the same

Comment: let parent = $('#'+selected.attr('class').split(' ').slice(-1).substr(7)); this doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suffixed or prefixed ClassNames are not the best when you have to deal with **references** in JavaScript.

#### Crazy selector

Just to target such suffixed class - the selector gets complicated:

```
[class^="parent_cat_"], [class*=" parent_cat_"]
```

you would better go using two classes in such case, one that is common to all your elements, and the specific one: `class="cat_checkbox parent_cat_42"`. That way the selector becomes as simple as

```
.cat_checkbox   // BETTER - Common class for all checkboxes
```

#### Too much work to extract the suffix Integer

**The problem** is that a *className* can house many names, and to find the desired one might be tricky.
How to get `42` out of `class="foo bar fooBar parent_cat_42 bla_bli_40"` ?

- Read the entire `classList`
- Find the one that matches this format `parent_cat_\d+`
- Retrieve it's index
- Extract it
- Get the digits
- Finally transform it to some ID `#cat_[ID]`

```js
const findIndex_parent_cat = klass => /^parent_cat_\d+$/.test(klass);
const findNum_parent_cat = klass => klass.replace(/\D+/, '');


$('[class^="parent_cat_"], [class*=" parent_cat_"]').on('change', function() {
  const klasses = $(this).attr('class');
  const ID = klasses.match(/(?:^|\s)parent_cat_(\d+)(?:$|\s)/)[1];
  const cat_ID = `#cat_${ID}`;
  console.log(`ID: ${cat_ID}`);
  $(cat_ID).prop({checked: this.checked});
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="main">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat_6" class="something parent_cat_0 bla" name="local[]">
    <label class="strong" for="cat_6">Stellenbeschreibungen</label>
    <ul>
      <li class="main">
        <input type="checkbox" id="doc_31" class="blue red inp parent_cat_6 foo bar" name="local[]">
        <label for="doc_31">Stellenbeschreibung Marketing/Vertrieb</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

#### Get class suffix Integer by using Regex

or it can be done by using Regex `(?:^|\s)parent_cat_(\d+)(?:$|\s)` :

```js
const findIndex_parent_cat = klass => /^parent_cat_\d+$/.test(klass);
const findNum_parent_cat = klass => klass.replace(/\D+/, '');


$('[class^="parent_cat_"], [class*=" parent_cat_"]').on('change', function() {
  const klasses = [...this.classList];
  const klassIndex = klasses.findIndex(findIndex_parent_cat); // Get index
  const klass = klasses[klassIndex]; // Find it in classList
  const ID = findNum_parent_cat(klass); // Now let's extract the N number ID
  const cat_ID = `#cat_${ID}`; // Finally we have the ID...
  
  console.log(`${klass} found in classList at index ${klassIndex}. ID: ${cat_ID}`);
  
  $(cat_ID).prop({checked: this.checked});
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="main">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat_6" class="something parent_cat_0 bla" name="local[]">
    <label class="strong" for="cat_6">Stellenbeschreibungen</label>
    <ul>
      <li class="main">
        <input type="checkbox" id="doc_31" class="blue red inp parent_cat_6 foo bar" name="local[]">
        <label for="doc_31">Stellenbeschreibung Marketing/Vertrieb</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

## Use `data-*` attribute instead!

Exactly, here's a remake of the above madness.
And yeah, see HTML how to use the `<label>` without the `for` attribute:

```js
$('[data-cat]').on('change', function() {

  const cat_ID = $(this).attr('data-cat'); // Finally we have the ID...
  console.log(`ID: ${cat_ID}`);
  
  $(cat_ID).prop({checked: this.checked});
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="main">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cat_6" data-cat="#cat_0" name="local[]">
      Stellenbeschreibungen
    </label>
    <ul>
      <li class="main">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="doc_31" data-cat="#cat_6" name="local[]">
          Stellenbeschreibung Marketing/Vertrieb
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```